# Is there a name for the quotient group of isomorphic permutations?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, terminology, definition

Suppose we have finite tuple $v$ of two (repeating) elements $x$ and $y$, the first occurring $m$ times, the second $n$ times.

Suppose we have a permutation $\pi \in S_{n+m}$. Then there are multiple permutations $\pi'$, such that $\pi(v) = \pi(v')$ (namely, those permutations that permute the $x$ and $y$ elements among themselves). For given $m$ and $n$ we can define an equivalence relation ~ on the permutations $\pi\in S_{n+m}$, such that $\pi ~\pi'$ if $\pi(v) = \pi'(v)$.

Is there a special name for the quotient group (or another group isomorphic to it)? I understand that this group will depend on $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Did you mean $S_{m+n}$ instead of $S_n$?

Comment: Also, I don't actually see any quotient group defined in your question. Can you be clearer about which quotient group you want a name for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, you probably mean $S_{n+m}$. Now, let $A$ be the set of all tuples of length $n + m$ with $m$ copies of $x$ and $n$ copies of $y$. There is an action of $S_{n + m}$ on $A$, which is $S_{n+m} \times A \longrightarrow A$ via $(\pi, v) \mapsto \pi(v)$. Now, to this group action we can associate the stabilizer of $v$, denoted $G_v = \{\pi \in S_{n+m} : \pi(v) = v\}$. This is a subgroup of $S_{n + m}$.

Now, the equivalence relation you defined was $\pi \sim \pi'$ if $\pi(v) = \pi'(v)$. This is equivalent to $\pi^{-1} \pi'(v) = v$, which is precisely the definition of $\pi^{-1} \pi' \in G_v$. So $\pi \sim \pi'$ if and only if $\pi^{-1} \pi' \in G_v$. The latter condition is precisely the equivalence relation defining the cosets $S_{n+m}/G_v$.

This is therefore the quotient you are looking for, but it is not necessarily a group. Well any finite set can easily be equipped with some group structure, but you probably mean $[\pi] [\pi'] = [\pi \pi']$, where the brackets denote the equivalence class. In other words, to rightly call this a quotient group would mean that there is a group structure on $S_{n+m}/G_v$ such that the quotient map $S_{n + m} \longrightarrow S_{n+m}/G_v$ is a group homomorphism. This is only possible if $G_v \subseteq S_{n + m}$ is a normal subgroup. However, it is not hard to compute that $\pi G_v \pi^{-1} = G_{\pi(v)}$. Thus, $G_v$ is normal in $S_{n+m}$ if and only if $G_v = G_{\pi(v)}$ for all $\pi \in S_{n+m}$. This is true in some trivial cases like $n = 0$ or $m = 0$ but it need not be true in general. So in general, this quotient is not a quotient group.

There is still a sort of multiplication on this quotient: the action of $S_{n+m}$ on it. While the product $[\pi] [\pi'] = [\pi \pi']$ is not well defined, the action $\pi [\pi'] = [\pi \pi']$ is. In coset notation, this is $\pi(\pi' G_v) = (\pi \pi') G_v$. So we cannot multiply two elements of the quotient, but we can left multiply by elements of $S_{n+m}$.

I'd like to point out another useful fact in analyzing this quotient. So far we have shown that $S_{n+m}/{\sim} = S_{n+m}/G_v$ and observed its action from $S_{n+m}$. There is a useful isomorphism (of sets with an $S_{n+m}$ action) of the latter object with the orbit of $v$. The orbit is defined $S_{n+m} v = \{\pi(v) : \pi \in S_{n + m}\} \subseteq A$. The isomorphism is described by $S_{n+m} / G_v \longrightarrow S_{n+m} v$ taking the coset $\pi G_v \mapsto \pi(v)$. That this is a well defined isomorphism is called the orbit stabilizer theorem.